# How can I make my displayAllValues rule to work recursively and deal with updated facts

Tags: prolog

I am new to Prolog and I had a challenge while I was trying to make my code recursive in nature so that, if I decided to add new facts to my dictionary it should be able to produce desired results.
And, I want to do it without using any pre-defined functions

Here is my scenario:

```
% some test facts
test(1,one,10).
test(2,two,60).
test(3,three,20).
test(4,four,60).
test(5,five,30).
test(6,six,60).

maxTest(_) :-
    test(_, Word, MaxValue), 
    \+ (test( _ , _ , Value), Value > MaxValue), 
    write(Word), 
    nl, 
    displayAllValues(Word, MaxValue).

displayAllValues(Word, MaxValue):-
     hr(_, Word1, MaxWins),
     hr(_, Word2, MaxWins),
     Word1 @< Word,
     Word2 @< Word1,
     write(Word1),
     nl,
     write(Word2),
     nl.
```

So, now the code gives me this output:

```
?- maxTest(Result).
two
four
six
R = R
```

So, what I am trying to do is to write all the Words with maximum value.

I am working with the NU Prolog 1.3. But, I clearly know that my code won't work accordingly if I added  new fact say,

```
test(7,seven,60).
```

So, what I a want my code to output is something like this,

```
?- maxTest(Result).
    two
    four
    six
    seven
    R = R
```

I tried to achieve this by do things like this for instance,

```
displayAllValues(_, Word, MaxValue):-
    \+ (test( _ , Word1, MaxValue),
        (   Word @<  Word1 ->
            write(Word1),
            nl
        )
      ).
```

No luck so far. Can anyone help me in figuring out how this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use predicate names that are more descriptive names than `test`, `maxTest`, and `displayAllValues`. Let the name of `test/3` reflect what the first, second, and third argument meas,, which domain they are drawn from, and how they relate to each other.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint:

```
displayAllValues(MaxValue):-
    forall(( test(_, Word1, Value), Value < MaxValue ), writeln(Word1)).

?- listing(displayAllValues).
displayAllValues(B) :-
    \+ ( test(_, C, A),
         A<B,
         \+ writeln(C)
       ).
```

[forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)(Condition, Action) is translated as shown by listing/1.

Comment: Thanks @CapelliC both ways worked. I just changed the condition to the way I want and that's it. I understood the 'forall' very well. But, still scratching my head regarding the '/+' case. I got you we did have \+ test() but, why do we need to have the '\+ writeln()'. Can you point me to a right place to read and understand more about this notation.

Comment: I think the SWI-Prolog documentation of [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) is very clear

Comment: I am using a different version of compiler and its NU Prolog I guess. It doesn't allow the usage of forall(). I actually read it online and yes it is clear. Thanks @CapelliC. I appreciate the help.